# modifying a filename extension on a php code

Tags: php

sorry because I don't know how to ask the question

I have here a code in php

```
$productDetails['country'][0]['image']
```

which output is:

```
http://localhost/wine-works.co.uk-tester/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/canada-wine_shop.jpg
```

how do I change the filename to look like this:

```
http://localhost/wine-works.co.uk-tester/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/canada-wine_shop-25x17.jpg
```

Comment: Look at php function [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

Comment: here is the result on print_r($productDetails['country'][0]);die();

Array ( [id] => 2192 [name] => Canada [description] => description here. [image] => http://localhost/website/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/canada-wine_shop.jpg [0] => Array ( [id] => 3089 [name] => Niagara [description] => [image] => ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$d = pathinfo($productDetails['country'][0]['image']);
echo $new_name = $d['dirname'].'/'.$d['filename'].'-25x17.'.$d['extension'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str= 'http://localhost/wine-works.co.uk-tester/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/canada-wine_shop.jpg';
$suffix = '-25x17';
$name = substr($str,strrpos($str,'/')+1);
$leftString = substr($str,0,strrpos($str,'/')+1);
$extension = substr($name,strrpos($name,'.'));
$nameNoExtension = substr($name,0,strrpos($name,'.'));
$string = $nameNoExtension.$suffix.$extension;
echo $leftString.$string;
//http://localhost/wine-works.co.uk-tester/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/canada-wine_shop-25x17.jpg
```